# Accessing File Metadata in Java < 1.7

Tags: java, file

In Java less than 1.7, if you want to get a file's metadata/attributes, say `lastModified`, the only way to get it is through the File instance's `.lastModified()` method.

If you don't have access to the file object and have only access to an `InputStream`/`OutputStream`, how can you access the underlying file's metadata/attributes?

A typical scenario where what I've described above might occur is when using some SDK functions like `.getResourceAsStream()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to use jna or jni and use native calls to the OS.

There is also cacls.exe on Windows might be useful. You could use ProcessBuilder to run it and then parse the output.

Both require files though. Not sure you can do anything with a stream